# arrayindexoutofbound exception while executing sql query on apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a table in Spark by using the below commands in Spark

```
case class trip(trip_id: String, duration: String, start_date: String, 
        start_station: String, start_terminal: String, end_date: String, 
        end_station: String, end_terminal: String, bike: String, 
        subscriber_type: String, zipcode: String)

    val trip_data = sc.textFile("/user/sankha087_gmail_com/trip_data.csv")

    val tripDF = trip_data
        .map(x=> x.split(","))
        .filter(x=> (x(1)!= "Duration"))
        .map(x=> trip(x(0),x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5),x(6),x(7),x(8),x(9),x(10)))
        .toDF() 

    tripDF.registerTempTable("tripdatas")

    sqlContext.sql("select * from tripdatas").show()
```

If I am running the above query (i.e. select *) , then I am getting desired result , but say if I run the below query , then I am getting the below exception :

```
sqlContext.sql("select count(1) from tripdatas").show()
```

> 18/03/07 17:59:55 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 2.
> 0 (TID 6, datanode1-cloudera.mettl.com, executor 1): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
> at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$3.apply(:31)
> at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$3.apply(:31)***

Comment: If error message is shown by `sqlContext.sql("select count(1) from tripdatas").show() ` then the error message should appear with `sqlContext.sql("select * from tripdatas").show()` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your data. If any of the lines in your data has less than 11 elements, you'll see that error.

You can try this to see the minimum number of columns in this way.

```
val trip_data = spark.read.csv("/user/sankha087_gmail_com/trip_data.csv")
println(trip_data.columns.length)
```

Comment: I am trying your suggested command , but getting the below exception: ` scala> val trip_data_sample = spark.read.csv("/user/sankha087_gmail_com/trip_data.csv")                                                              
<console>:25: error: not found: value spark                                                                                                          
         val trip_data_sample = spark.read.csv("/user/sankha087_gmail_com/trip_data.csv") ` Please help

Comment: 'spark' is just spark session that is automatically created if you're using a spark shell. If you are writing a spark app, just substitute it with whatever sparkSession you're generating.

And that was just a handy way of looking at the number of columns in your data. You can always do a manual inspection if the file isn't too large.